# Printing directly to a Zebra/Swecoin TTP2030 receipt printer in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, printing, drivers, zebra-printers, cups

I have a Swecoin/Zebra TTP2030 USB-LPT receipt printer that I am using on Ubuntu.  I'd like to use it like a normal printer, which Zebra says is possible under Windows.  Anyone know anyway to do this under Ubuntu?  I've tried a few printer drivers, and I just get reams and reams of the printer code printed out.  Anyone have any insight on getting this thing running like a normal printer?

I already have it communicating via the ttputil: http://www.rainbow-software.org/linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it, and the good news is that these printers have been added to CUPS 1.5, so it should "just work" on new systems.  But I'm on Ubuntu/lucid, so I did it like this:

1. downloaded zebraCupsDrivers_v2.zip from http://www.cups.org/str.php?L3767
2. installed via gnome `system-config-printer-applet`
3. used ttp20x0.ppd in *ppd/* from zebraCupsDrivers_v2.zip
4. built rastertozebrakiosk in *filters* from zebraCupsDrivers_v2.zip by doing:

   1. `apt-get install libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev`
   2. `gcc -o rastertozebrakiosk rastertozebrakiosk.c -lcups -lcupsimage`
   3. `cp rastertozebrakiosk /usr/lib/cups/filter/`

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the device added, you should be able to print from the command line.

```
$ lpr file.prn
```

You'll need to create an output file using the printer's native code.

Comment: I want to treat it like a normal printer, I just figured this out.  I want to post the answer, but Stack Overflow won't let me for another 6 hours...